# WPF Browser aplication en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Tengo una aplicación WPF que me permite usar el sdk de digital persona para capturar huellas, y tengo una aplicación web que manda a llamar el exe generado de la aplicación wpf, pero deseo ejecutar esa aplicación desde una aplicación o sitio web.

La forma en la que ejecuto la aplicación desde asp.net es esta:

```
Process programa = new Process();
programa.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;           
ProcessStartInfo info = null;

info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:/Users/rutaapp.exe"); //Aquí va la ruta de la aplicación física.

programa = Process.Start(info);
```

Funciona perfecto, pero deseo tener comunicación entre la aplicación wpf y la web.

Leí que puedo hacer una aplicación tipo WPF Browser Application ya que al parecer me permite ejecutar vía web una aplicación tipo Forms, pero cuando abro Visual Studio no me aparece ese tipo de proyecto, sólo me aparece WPF Application.

Alguien sabe cómo puedo tener ese proyecto? o cómo realizar la comunicación entre esas dos aplicaciones?? Gracias.

Comment: no termino de comprender. esa app se ejecuta del lado del servidor. de que te serviria en un entorno web?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que quiero hacer un sitio web que permita leer las huellas de una persona, sin problema lo tengo en app de Escritorio, pero ahora quiero hacerlo en un sitio web, solo que he leido que no se puede hacer tan directamente.

Comment: de acuerdo, pero no puede llevar la app local a la web. .cuando la ejecutes, va a esperar input del lado del servidor, no del cliente.

Comment: Sabes de alguna forma de resolver este dilema?? Pude hacerlo mandando a llamar a la app (aunque esté del lado del cliente) pero no sé como interactuar con ellas.

Comment: es que no puedes. como vas a hacer para que el usuario del otro lado de la web, ponga su dedo donde esta el servidor? No tengo ni idea si se pueden leer huellas desde una app en la web.. ni se si el navegador te deja acceder a eso.. y eso es lo que tenes que averiguar...

Comment: Mmmmm es que una solución que encontré es tener la app de lectura de huellas local, mandada a llamar por la Web, leer los datos (huella) y mandarlos a la web para ya después ahí procesarlos, pero no sé como hacer eso o si sea posible.

Comment: o sea el usuario se descarga la app y la corre local.. entonces para que necesita la web.. que lo haga todo la app ;)

Comment: Buen punto XD jejejeje pero bueno, es que estuve leyendo de WPF Browser Application, que al parecer me hubiera permitido hacer eso, inclusive hay tutoriales de cómo correr una win form en wpf browser, pero en mi visual studio no me aparece el tipo de proyecto wpf browser app y deseaba saber por qué o como corregirlo

Comment: imagino que estas WPF Browser Application utiliza Silverligh, este tipo de desarrollo no existe

Comment: eh no @LeandroTuttini.. yo lo acabo de encontrar y segun la documentacion tiene razon. hay que ver como funciona, pero en mi VS esta...

Comment: Es que en mi VS no está :/ que versión tienes??

Comment: te paso los print en el [chat]

Comment: Ok, ya que entre ahí qué debo hacer???

Comment: solo tienes que entrar... nada mas...

Comment: Ok ya estoy ahí

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76172/discussion-between-erik-and-gbianchi).

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que la integracion que buscar no se puede realizar, un desarrollo web esta limitado al acceso a dispositivos en la pc del usuario.

Quizas habria alguna posibilidad cuando existian las `ActiveX` o `Silverlight`, pero estas opciones estan deprecadas.

Si necesitas una autenticacion por huella entonces tu desarollo no es web, quizas podrias autenticar de esta forma para acceder a servivio web, como ser wcf o webapi, pero solo para autenticar y obtener el token de seguridad.

Si ejecutas un .exe desde el codigo .net del sitio este correra en el servidor, no en el cliente, que no ten confunda el hecho que estas desarrollando local, con lo cual servidor y cliente estan en la misma pc, esto no sera asi cuando realices en deploy en el hosting.

Comment: encontre esto: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-xaml-browser-applications-overview#creating_a_new_xaml_browser_application_xbap.. hay que probarlo.. pero... pareceria ser lo que OP necesita...

Comment: claro es lo que decia, eso genera un xbap, eso es Silverlight, ya no tiene soporte

Answer (score 0):

Has una cosa, a ver : teneos por una parte la app wpf (supongo que c sharp) y la web, tan simple como poner el punto intermedio en la base de datos. Utilizando una base de datos como puente enviaras de la app wpf al servidor y por el otro lado, desde la web, recuperar los datos que insertastes desde el wpf. Fin